# MobileFirst Platform 6.3 - web resource changes do not get applied

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

On my laptop when I change the Javascript of my Cordova app and refresh the preview page all my changes are reflected right away.

Today I installed Eclipse Luna with MobileFirst Platform 6.3 on my desktop machine but my Javascript changes require me to redeploy the app to reflect, if I just refresh the preview page I get an old version of the app, how can I change the behavior to be similar to my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: the fix is now available from either IBM Fix Central or by updating from Eclipse Marketplace.

---

The behavior your are referring to is called 'fast preview', where upon saving any web resource change in Studio will be displayed by a refresh in the browser, w/out needing to re-build and deploy the web resources.

This feature got broken due to a regression. It has been identified to be introduced in a recent 6.3 iFix release.
It is in the process of being fixed; you'll need to wait a little while longer for the fix to arrive.

If you'd like, you can open a PMR to get an iFix once the fix is published, or check once in a few days for updates to your installed plug-in via Eclipse > Help > Check for updates.