# MobileFirst Eclipse not detecting changes

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I have recently updated my eclipse mobilefirst studio to 6.3.0.00-20150106-1717
There after  when I make any changes in HTML/Css/Js the changes are not reflected in the worklight we based simulator. Inorder to get the changes on the weh based simulator, i have to use run as -> run on mobilefirst development server.

In the previous version before this update what all changes in HTML/CSS/js was immediately reflected in the web based worklight simulator
Please advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [MobileFirst Platform 6.3 - web resource changes do not get applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972297/mobilefirst-platform-6-3-web-resource-changes-do-not-get-applied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the fix is now available from either IBM Fix Central or by updating from Eclipse Marketplace.

---

Duplicate of: [MobileFirst Platform 6.3 - web resource changes do not get applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972297/mobilefirst-platform-6-3-web-resource-changes-do-not-get-applied/)

This is a known regression. A fix will be available, soon.
Check back for updates in either IBM Fix Central, or via Eclipse > Help > Check for updates in the near future.

There is no local workaround.